# Can't use a namespace in a Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have this Controller :

```
namespace FacilitaTripBundle\Controller;

use FacilitaTripBundle\Api\models\GuideDestination\GuideDestinationModel;
use FacilitaTripBundle\Api\models\Destination\DestinationModel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * @Route("/api/v1", name="api")
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * @Route("/destinations/get_all_minimal/", name="destination_get_minimal")
   */
  public function getMinimalAction()
  {
    $model = new DestinationModel();
    $data = $model->getAllMinimal();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * @Route("/guideDestination/getLastAddDestination/", name="destination_last_add_destination")
   */
  public function getLastAddDestinationAction()
  {
    $guide_destination_model = new GuideDestinationModel();
    $data = $guide_destination_model->getLastAddDestination();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
  }
}
```

I got this error :

```
Attempted to load class "GuideDestinationModel" from namespace "FacilitaTripBundle\Api\models\GuideDestination".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace
```

I define the class GuideDestinationModel in this file :

```
namespace FacilitaTripBundle\Api\models\GuideDestination;

class GuideDestinationModel {
}
```

How you got an idea why I got this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the physical path to file containing `GuideDestinationModel` class?

According to [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), which Symfony is using, you are supposed to put class definitions in path which corresponds to your namespace like in following example.

> \Symfony\Core\Request =>
>   /path/to/project/lib/vendor/Symfony/Core/Request.php

I notice you have lowercase `models` in your `FacilitaTripBundle\Api\models\GuideDestination` namespace. Is your directory `models` also lowercase? If not this might be the issue here if you are using system which is case sensitive when it comes to path resolving (i.e. Linux)

Comment: The path of the class is `src/FacilitaTripBundle/Api/models/GuideDestination/GuideDestination.php` so it should be good ..